# Handling Database related projects among teams members

Tags: php, mysql, projects-and-solutions

We are a team of 10 members. We are developing a project with php and mysql. To keep the code in Sync we use SVN. but major of our configurations and content are stored in DB. So how can we keep the DB also in sync with all users. Which is the best method in handling such projects in teams ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you look for a solution for syncronising database-related changes between developers and software versions (i.e. field changes, table changes), not changed data itself.

A good solution for this is [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/):

> Liquibase is an open source (Apache 2.0 Licensed),
>   database-independent library for tracking, managing and applying
>   database changes. It is built on a simple premise: All database
>   changes are stored in a human readable yet trackable form and checked
>   into source control.

Comment: does it sync the Data changes also?

Comment: No it doesn't. If you want to synchronize data between different database servers, other tools are better suited for this. So what is it, database changes or data changes?

Comment: - its data changes inside the table.

Comment: Then you should use a tool to synchronize the data. If you want the data really fast, maybe use MySQL Replication. If the data is more static, use batch driven Synchronization (p.e. mysql_dump). If you want different kind of data, maybe use configuration files to populate your tables like your projects needs it.